# Given $c =\sqrt {a^2-b^2}$, $c= ea$, conclude that $\frac {2\pi ab}{(a+c)T} =\frac {2\pi a}T\sqrt {\frac {1-e}{1+e}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $c =\sqrt {a^2-b^2}$, $c= ea$, conclude that $$\frac {2\pi ab}{(a+c)T} =\frac {2\pi a}T\sqrt {\frac 
{1-e}{1+e}}$$

Sorry for the awful formatting of this question. I know this is a pretty simple problem, but for some reason I cannot figure it out. The furthest I have gotten is reducing the b in the numerator to $\sqrt {a^2(1-e)}$, but then I get stuck. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for introduction to $\LaTeX$. Skip the introduction of [this](https://math-on-quora.surge.sh) (because the introduction is different and does not apply to this site, rest is same).

Comment: I reformatted your post, please check to see that I didn't introduce any errors.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: To your question:  As a first step you should make the obvious cancellations.  Why leave the expression with so many cancellable terms?

Comment: typo? why $c$ is assigned 2 values.

Comment: Specific question:  I have no idea whether you intended what I wrote for the square root term on the right or if you intended $\sqrt {\frac {1-e}{1+e}}$.  I just guessed...what you wrote was ambiguous.

Comment: Your formulas are inconsistent. Do you mean $c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$?

Comment: @Pythagoras yes, thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;c =\sqrt {a^2-b^2},\;$ we get $\;b=\sqrt {a^2-c^2}$.

Moreover,

$$\frac {2\pi ab}{(a+c)T} =\frac{2\pi a\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}{T(a+c)}=\frac{2\pi a}T\sqrt{\frac 
{(a+c)(a-c)}{(a+c)^2}}=\frac{2\pi a}T\sqrt{\frac 
{a-c}{a+c}}=\frac{2\pi a}T\sqrt{\frac 
{a-ea}{a+ea}}=\frac{2\pi a}T\sqrt{\frac 
{a(1-e)}{a(1+e)}}=\frac{2\pi a}T\sqrt{\frac 
{1-e}{1+e}}.$$